# Bash: declaration of an alias to be used in a single lined multiple commands

Tags: bash

I would like to do something like

```
alias myls=ls && myls
```

This gives me an error

```
bash: myls: command not found
```

Strangely, a subsequent

```
myls
```

in the same session would be recognized.

Do you know how to declare alias, that is used in the same command sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are  somewhat  confusing.
>   Bash  always  reads  at least one complete line of input before executing any of
>   the commands on that line.  **Aliases are expanded when a  command  is  read,  not
>   when  it is executed.  Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line
>   as another command does not take effect until the next line of  input  is  read.**
>   The commands following the alias definition on that line are not affected by the
>   new alias.  This behavior is also an issue when functions are executed.  Aliases
>   are  expanded  when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed,
>   because a function definition is itself a compound command.  As a  consequence,
>   aliases  defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed.
>   To be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate  line,
>   and do not use alias in compound commands.
>
> **For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.**

Answer (score 1):

`alias` has to be used on a separate line so even this won't work:

```
alias myls=ls; myls
```

This will result in `-bash: myls: command not found` error.

However, you can use `function` and use it on same line:

```
myls() { ls "$@"; } && myls
```

Answer (score 1):

[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) has already provided a better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741218/6394138), but if for some reason you don't want to use a function instead of an alias then you can do

```
alias myls=ls && eval myls
```

Note, however, that usage of `eval` introduces an extra level of expansion, which may result in unexpected behaviour for more complex commands:

```
$ echo "A    B"
A    B
$ eval echo "A    B"
A B
$ echo '$SHELL'
$SHELL
$ eval echo '$SHELL'
/bin/bash
```